# How can I run a Silk4J test from the command line?

Tags: silktest

I have read the official [MicroFocus article "How can I run a Silk4J test from the command line?"](http://community.microfocus.com/borland/test/silk_test/w/knowledge_base/19219.how-can-i-run-a-silk4j-test-from-the-command-line.aspx) but doing as described results in the message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLoggerContext.getLogger(SLF4JLoggerContext.java:41)
```

So it seems there are more JARs to be added to the class path than described in the article, which is from 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had too many JAR files in my classpath.

Removing the following JARs enhanced the situation:

- `log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.2.jar`
- `log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.2-javadoc.jar`
- `log4j-to-slf4j-2.0.2-sources.jar`
- `log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.2.jar`
- `log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.2-javadoc.jar`
- `log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.2-sources.jar`

(where the JavaDoc and Sources were probably not an issue).